# How to get latitude and longitude data from the borders of a state in R

Tags: r, maps, geospatial, shapefile, geo

Here is my problem: I need to get longitude and latitude data from the borders of the Brazilian states. With this data I can plot a map of each Brazilian state and, of course, of the whole country.

I'm quite new to R but I know it has some packages to plot maps and also to get latitude and longitude data from cities, countries, etc.

The problem is that I need latitude and longitude from the bordes of each state and not just the map. I need the data to after construct the map and I don't know if it's possible to get this sort of data in R.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You're looking for a shapefile. There are lots of sources, of varying quality. Here's [one](http://gadm.org/download).

Comment: I tried to download the data in R format but when I open it R gives this message: `> load("/Users/myuser/Downloads/BRA_adm0.rds")
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘BRA_adm0.rds’ has magic number 'X'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated`

Comment: You need to use a package that understands the data. I usually use `rgdal::readOGR` to load shapefiles.

Comment: Oops, it actually says to use `sp::readRDS` in the documentation.

Comment: Also, you probably want "level 1" (`BRA_adm1.rds`) if you want states. I think "level 0" is just the outline of the country.

Comment: Thank you @alistaire!! Now I'm trying to understand where is the longitude and latitude data in this `.rds` file. I need them. I've never worked with GIS before and I'm facing problems with it

Comment: If you imported with `brazil <- readRDS('BRA_adm1.rds')`, then it's in `brazil@polygons`. It's pretty useless to look at though; it's basically 10Mb of lat-long pairs. You need a package to plot it; there are many. `leaflet` is nice. `ggplot2` can do it.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of data but I actually need this. Do you know how can I export this to a `.csv`, `.txt`, `xlsx`... file? The command `brazil@polygons` only shows me the data in the prompty of R. It does not give the possibility to use this data.

Comment: You can hack it out of `brazil@polygons` with some careful subsetting, but you're going to lose information when you do so, especially if you simplify it to the point that you can write it to a .csv. What are you trying to do with it? What's the end-goal here?

Comment: See here for an example: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176839/how-to-compute-max-and-min-coordinates-for-multiple-polygons/176841#176841  check out the code just after ## cast to lines and then to points

Comment: `choroplethrAdmin1::get_admin1_map('brazil')` may be easier for what you want; it just has `lat` and `long` columns.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want to download the shp file and not the r poly file. You can then simply unzip and then use the maptools package to load the shape file.

```
require(maptools)
brazil <- readShapeLines("BRA_adm0.shp")
plot(brazil)
```

This will actually produce a plot of the outline of brazil. I believe you can simply layer on the additional shp files using plot. You may have to merge the spatial lines data frames to use other graphics packages such as ggplot2.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for plotting the outline of Brazil but I'm trying to understand where is the data for longitude and latitude in a shapefile. I've nerver worked with GIS before (I'm an statistician) so I'm having problems with it.

Comment: Do I need to convert the shape file to a long/lat file?

Comment: There are a number of different shape files in the zip folder. It looks like they each contain information on different administrative levels. Just load some of the other files. I think that "BRA_adm1.shp" has state level administrative regions.